# Tensorflow: Batch TFRecord Dataset with tensors of arbitrary dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow

### How can I batch tensors of arbitrary shapes using the TFRecordsDataset?

I am currently working on the input pipeline of an object detection Network and am struggeling with the batching of my labels. The labels consist of Bounding Box coordinates and classes of the Objects in an image. Since there may be multiple objects in an image the label **dimensions are arbitrary**

---

When working with `tf.train.batch` there is the possibility to set `dynamic_padding=True` to fit the shapes to the same dimensions. However there is no such option in the `data.TFRecordDataset.batch()`.

The desired shape i would like to batch would be `[batch_size, arbitrary , 4]` for my Boxes and `[batch_size, arbitrary, 1]` for the classes.

```
def decode(serialized_example):
"""
Decodes the information of the TFRecords to image, label_coord, label_classes
Later on will also contain the Image Sequence!

:param serialized_example: Serialized Example read from the TFRecords
:return: image, label_coordinates list, label_classes list
"""
features = {'image/shape': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'train/image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'label/coordinates': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
            'label/classes': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string)}

features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=features)

image_shape = tf.decode_raw(features['image/shape'], tf.int64)
image = tf.decode_raw(features['train/image'], tf.float32)
image = tf.reshape(image, image_shape)

# Contains the Bounding Box coordinates in a flattened tensor
label_coord = features['label/coordinates']
label_coord = label_coord.values
label_coord = tf.reshape(label_coord, [1, -1, 4])

# Contains the Classes of the BBox in a flattened Tensor
label_classes = features['label/classes']
label_classes = label_classes.values
label_classes = tf.reshape(label_classes, [1, -1, 1])


return image, label_coord, label_classes
```

---

```
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename)
    dataset = dataset.map(decode)
    dataset = dataset.map(augment)
    dataset = dataset.map(normalize)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

---

The error that is thrown is `Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 1. First element had shape [1,1,4] and element 1 had shape [1,7,4].`

Also currently the `augment` and `normalize` functions are just placeholders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` has an other function called `padded_batch` which is basically doing the thing `tf.train.batch(dynamic_pad=True)` does. This solves the proble rather easily...

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename)

dataset = dataset.map(decode)
dataset = dataset.map(augment)
dataset = dataset.map(normalize)

dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000+3*batch_size)
dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(batch_size,
                               drop_remainder=False,
                               padded_shapes=([None, None, None],
                                              [None, 4],
                                              [None, 1])
                              )
```